# MATLAB: Plot with For Loop Fixed Variables

Tags: matlab, loops

In MATLAB, I have following output of data from a script:

```
A1 = [1 2;3 4]
A2 = [2 2; 4 5]
A3 = [3 5; 7 8]
```

I need to create a for loop to step through the each variable and plot.
Something like:

```
for i = 1:3
plot(A(i))
end
```

So A1 will generate a plot.  A2 will generate a plot.  And A3 will generate a plot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop using `eval` (will emulate variable variable) and `figure` (will create a figure for each A):

```
A1 = [1 2;3 4];
A2 = [2 2; 4 5];
A3 = [3 5; 7 8];

for i = 1:3
    figure(i);
    eval(['plot(A' num2str(i) ');'])
end
```

If you have many As you might want to save the plots automatically, by inserting the following line right after the eval line in the loop:

```
print('-dpng','-r100',['A' int2str(i)])
```

Comment: @user1608954 I strongly recommend against using eval and rather adjusting your script to make a cell matrix A such that A{1} == A1 etc... using eval is opening yourself up to a world of error, it's difficult to debug, difficult to read and difficult to maintain.

Comment: +1 for showing the use of figure() though, both other answers forgot to include it.

Comment: in addition to what @Dan said: it's also not very 'Matlab'-ish to use ``A1, A2, A3`` and not ``A{1}, A{2}, A{3}``.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is use `eval`

```
for ii = 1:3
   cmd = sprintf('plot( A%d );', ii );
   eval( cmd );
end
```

However, using `eval` is not recommended. The best way is if you can alter the code generating `A1`...`A3`, so it can either create a cell array `A{1}`,...`A{3}`, or even struct fields `S.A1`,...,`S.A3`.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you alter the script that outputs those variables to rather stick them in a cell array or a struct.

If that's not possible then if there are only 3 I would suggest you stick them in a cell array manually i.e. `A{1} = A1; A{2} = A2; A{3} = A3`

Only if you really really can't do either of those, you should consider using `eval`

```
for ii = 1:n
    eval(['plot(A', num2str(ii), ')']);
end
```

to debug I suggest replacing `eval` with `disp` to make sure you are generating the right code